# Working with GB SRTM Digital Elevation Model (DEM) 90m

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I have downloaded the **[freely available DEM file](http://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/5)** from sharegeo open.

I would like to know for a set of points at what elevation they lie. I have imported the DEM file into ArcGIS but it seems strange; the highest point is 63.

I was wondering if anyone else has experience with this dataset or similar and could shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, rather than use the 90m DEM for GB which seems to be problematic, why not use the freely available 50m DEM from OS OpenData ([Land-Form Panorama](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html)) instead?  It is available as vector contours or raster grid for the whole of Great Britain (including the Shetland Islands, which are excluded from the GB-SRTM dataset).  It is not without some errors, but the Panorama DEM is a better resolution and has not required patching and hole filling like the SRTM data and is a stable product providing consistent results.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks, I'm going to proceed using the dataset mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded the dataset and I think there is some sort of corruption as when it loaded for me the highest point was about 800m so about 500m lower than Ben Nevis! So unless some sort of tectonic shift has occurred without anyone in the UK noticing me thinks something is amiss!

I ran the [Build Pyramids and Statistics Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m9000000) accepting defaults and this resolved the problem

Comment: Haha yes very odd. Your solution worked for me, thanks. However, due to the limitations outlined above I've decided to conduct the analysis with the alternative dataset.

Answer (score 0):

When I import the raster dataset and create pyramids it shows values from 0 to 1289,27. I guess you'll have to calculate statistics and/or build pyramids in order for it to show correctly. I tested with ArcMap 10.1.